# Inflate in AlertDialog custom view and get information entered

Tags: android

I need to insert in AlertDialog view a custom view with sub elements, like EditText. This works well, but when user click in AlertDialog ok button, I need to get the information of sub elements, but instead of get the text that I inserted in UI I get empty string or null pointers like can see in Log.e() in code.

AlertDialog:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alert.setTitle("Title");

alert.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.sonidovideo, null ) );
alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


    EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.segundos);
    EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.segundosFin);
    EditText c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.segundosInicio);
    Spinner d = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.calidades);
    Spinner e = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.detecciones);


    Log.e("Is null", (a==null) + ""); //False
    Log.e("No text",(a.getText().toString().compareTo("")==0) + ""); //True

    Log.e("Is null", (b==null) + ""); //True

    Log.e("Is null", (c==null) + ""); //True

    Log.e("Is null", (d==null) + ""); //True

    Log.e("Is null", (e==null) + ""); //True



    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    dialog.cancel();
}
});
alert.show();
```

R.layour.sonidovideo(sonidosvideo.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/segundosInicio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/segundos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>



<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/detecciones"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:entries="@array/detecciones" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/segundosFin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/calidades"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/segundosFin"
    android:entries="@array/calidades" />
```

For get te sub items I also try this but the result is the same

```
EditText a = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.sonidovideo, null ).findViewById(R.id.segundos);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
EditText a = (EditText)  alert.findViewById(R.id.segundos);
EditText b = (EditText)  alert.findViewById(R.id.segundosFin);
EditText c = (EditText)  alert.findViewById(R.id.segundosInicio);
Spinner d = (Spinner)  alert.findViewById(R.id.calidades);
Spinner e = (Spinner)  alert. findViewById(R.id.detecciones);
```

Since you are inflating the layout dynamically, you have to specify the layout that has these views.